# Text on website moves in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser

I have almost finished my portfolio page , but on one of my pages I have a error when displaying on firefox , on the http://www.jn-design.co.uk/about.html page the skills section on the right has moved a paragraph of my text (The cv lines). This is not a issue within any other browsers , just firefox!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it intentional that the bottom half of your top logo disappears when you scroll?

Comment: Yes , Its a tad big when the user reads something , thats why it re appears on scroll up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually looks fine in Firefox but is broken on Chrome. Anyway, try adding a "clear: both" style to the last paragraph that contains the cv lines.

Comment: Hmm , It appears fine in my chrome , possibly its resolution problem? I have added a clear , and this has not solved the problem!

Comment: Yep the right layout is : www.jn-design.co.uk/right.png , and the wrong one is www.jn-design.co.uk/wrong.png

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions , I really cant figure it out

Comment: Weird, I see the exact wrong layout in Chrome, and the right one in Firefox.

Anyway, you added the style clear:both to #cvs, should be .cvs as that's a class.